# How to convert uri in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I need to convert a python by uri

```
D:\*****\******\******\testing.txt
```

to

```
file:///D:/*****/******/*****/testing.txt
```

how can I do. Thank you

I edited because I was wrong the final uri, sorry

Comment: It looks like you just want to add `file:///` to the string you have, do a simple string concatenation.

Comment: Damn it. It's just a simple string concatenation. Have you tried something?

Comment: With  `def GETLISTA():
    iptvset = int(addon.getSetting('iptvset')) + 1
    lista = addon.getSetting('lista' + str(iptvset))
    return lista`  
I withdraw the type of uri from a menu in xml,
but if I insert a url I have no problems, but if you select a file on the hard disk, it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on what HarryCBurn has done, the slashes will also need changing.

```
path = r"D:\*****\******\******\testing.txt"   #the original string
path = "file:///" + path                       #text concatenation
path = path.replace("\\","/")                  #changing the slashes
print path
```

if you wanted to treat some strings differently - such as those starting with "htt" then this could work

```
path1 = r"D:\*****\******\******\testing.txt"   #the original string
path2 = r"http: // *****"

def pathedit(path):
    if path.startswith("http"):                       #checks if the list starts with htt
        return path                             #Returns value
    path = "file:///" + path                #text concatenation
    path = path.replace("\\","/")           #changing the slashes
    return path                             #Returns value

print pathedit(path1)
print pathedit(path2)
```

Comment: I thank you for the answers, this works if the list is a hard disk file, but if the list and a network url, does not work, my goal is to be able to use a file from the network list via http or from hard drives                          `'def GETLISTA():
    iptvset = int(addon.getSetting('iptvset')) + 1
    lista = addon.getSetting('lista' + str(iptvset))
    lista = "file:///" + lista                       #text concatenation
    return lista'`

Comment: if you can provide examples of the paths and examples of the results you expect that would help

Comment: I tried this last suggestion, but so does not work, I would need something like: If the list starts with http character, then list = http: // ***** if different, the list = "file:///" + lista

Answer (score 0):

Just a string concatenation:

```
text = "your line here"
text = "file:///" + text
```

Comment: I tried this last suggestion, but so does not work, I would need something like: If the list starts with http character, then list = http: // *****
if different, the list = "file:///" + lista